# Configuration contain properties not supported

Tags: maven, jboss-arquillian

I finished following the JPA tutorial at http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/ , but when I try to run the test ("Run the Test on GlassFish" section of the guide) as JUnit I obtain the following messages:

> Avvertenza: Configuration contain properties not supported by the
>   backing object
>   org.jboss.arquillian.container.weld.ee.embedded_1_1.WeldEEMockConfiguration
>   Unused property entries:
>   {resourcesXml=src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded/glassfish-resources.xml}
>   Supported property names: [enableConversationScope]

Here down the **glassfish-resources.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC
    "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
        jndi-name="jdbc/arquillian"/>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="ArquillianEmbeddedDerbyPool"
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource"
        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="false">
        <property name="databaseName" value="target/databases/derby"/>
        <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.avh4.util</groupId>
      <artifactId>imagecomparison</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <profile>
      <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
      <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
      <testResources>
          <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          </testResource>
          <testResource>
          <directory>src/test/resources-glassfish-embedded</directory>
          </testResource>
      </testResources>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
          <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
              <java.util.logging.config.file>
                  ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/logging.properties
              </java.util.logging.config.file>
              <derby.stream.error.file>
                  ${project.build.directory}/derby.log
              </derby.stream.error.file>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
          </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
</project>
```

**Eclipse's console:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container glassfish-embedded
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DeployableContainer must be specified
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    ... 39 more
```

It is strange because I literally followed the guide, without making any different change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, going by the guide, you should be expecting the GlassFish container to be used. Obviously the wrong container is configured to be used in your tests, since the log displays Weld as the one used for testing.

You will need to verify that the Arquillian Glassfish container adapter is present in your classpath. Additionally, you'll also need ensure that the Weld container is absent. All of this is present in [this section of the tutorial on preparing the test to use GlassFish](http://arquillian.org/guides/testing_java_persistence/#prep_the_test_for_glassfish).

Note the use of the `arquillian-bom` dependency in the `dependencyManagement` section of the project POM, in addition to

- `arquillian-junit-container` (for JUnit support in Arquillian),
- `arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1` (the Arquillian GlassFish container adapter), and
- `glassfish-embedded-web` (embedded GlassFish) dependencies.

Comment: The dependencies you mentioned were present in pom.xml, but I did not commented weld's stuff. Now I did it and I edited the previous post adding the new pom.xml but I am having new troubles, in particular:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

Comment: Can I see the entire stack trace? You could update your question with it.

Comment: Ok I added the Eclipse console messages

Comment: I think it's better I give you the green mark and I open another question, since the topic has been solved. Do you agree?